# Why apache spark throw an exception when a try to get an spark configuration

Tags: java, apache-spark, configuration

When I try to do this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkUnitTest").setMaster("local[*]");
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(conf)
                .getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext sparkContext = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes")
```

I am receiving this error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.files.maxPartitionBytes
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because the setting is actually `spark.**sql**.files.maxPartitionBytes`?

Comment: Can you add your code before?

Comment: Yes, code added

Answer (score 0):

The configuration property you are looking for is:

```
spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes
```

And not:

```
spark.files.maxPartitionBytes
```

See more details in [spark sql performance tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)

Comment: Doesn't work too, the same error. This configuration exists in Spark 3.1.1, but seems that if I don't change the default value it stays empty/null. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/configuration.html#spark-properties

Answer (score 0):

**Viewing Spark Properties**

"The application web UI at http://:4040 lists Spark properties in the “Environment” tab. This is a useful place to check to make sure that your properties have been set correctly. **Note that only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear**. *For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used*."

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/configuration.html#spark-properties